# Excel COUNTIF function with multiple columns and lines

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've a sheet where i want to count the "X" of cell as the next example:

[image]

I put the formulas in order to example what I want to do!

Someone can help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `B3`, formula copied across and down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+((($E3:$I3="X")*$E$2:$I$2)=0+RIGHT(B$2)))
```

[image]